# Error on DataGridView reading a certain Field

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm creating a program for a company I'm currently in internship, one part of it is being able to see the data from their SQL 2014 server.

I used a DatagridViewe to get the data from the SQL server and at first it works

[image]

But if I scroll sideways it shows me this error

[image]

I tried searching but I couldn't find anyone with the same problem

```vb
Private Sub dothesearch()

    Dim comandstring As String

    If combo_basededados.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        comandstring = "SELECT * FROM PRITESTES.dbo.RegrasDescPrec"
    Else
        comandstring = "SELECT * FROM PRITESTES.dbo.EscaloesRegrasDescPrec"
    End If

    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(conectionsString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim comand As New SqlCommand(comandstring, conn)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comand.ExecuteReader
        Dim datatableusing As New DataTable
        datatableusing.Load(reader)
        DTGV.DataSource = datatableusing

    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Change the language of the machine. I don't even understand what the error even says. Though i saw some keywords and i guess it has(maybe) failed to parse some image.

Comment: From what event are you calling `dothesearch` ?

Comment: Can you add the definition of the Grids columns as well as the database tables please? From initial looks, I think you are trying to add/display an image but it has trouble rendering it.

Comment: I vividly remember having this error too, it was because the Indexing of row/column was different than the indexing of table in SQL. See if you can modify column headers and if error persists.

Comment: You MUST be doing something BEFORE/AFTER you run the posted `dothesearch` code above. I am guessing you are getting a valid `DataTable` from the query… otherwise you would be getting an error from the query. It appears the error is clearly coming from the `DataGridView` and it is an error of type `DataError.` I suggest you wire up the grids `DataError` event to get more info.

Comment: The error indicates that “something” in one of the cells in the grid contains a value that is the “WRONG” type for that cell. This could be a string of characters in an `int` column, or a combo box value that is not in the combo boxes items. If the offending “cell” is NOT displayed in the viewable area of the grid when the row is added to the grid… nothing will happen. However, as soon as the offending cell is “scrolled” into the viewable area of the grid… you will get the error you see. What else are you doing before or after this code is run? Are you adding any rows/columns to the grid?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uC2FPFw Here's the table's fields and here's the data in them https://imgur.com/i1IZKNn. These seem to be the only ones with issues loading. I don't do any code after of before, i just use a button click event to summon that code. And yes in both those tables those variables are the same. Sorry for the delay

Comment: Hmmm. There is still something missing. In the picture from your last comment that shows the column name, data type etc.… I can see Moeda, TipoRegra, Campo1 and Campo2 that match the columns in the picture posted here, however, I do not see the columns TipoSugesto, PeriodoValidade, DataInicial and a few more columns that are NOT shown in the table columns posted in the picture. Where are these columns coming from? They are not in the data table shown in the picture.

Comment: Also, to find out which column is causing the problem… scroll the grid to the right, as soon as you get the data error, the problem column is the one that is to the right of the LAST displayed column in the viewable grid. Example: from the picture, the Desconto3 column is ok because we can see the values in the column. Therefore, if you get the data error before the next column displays, then, the problem column is the one right after the Desconto3 column.

Comment: Lastly, the VersaoUltAct column looks strange. It is a data type of `timestamp`? and the data looks like a hex number. How is this “timestamp” object being converted from a hex number to a time or date object? I know the grid won’t do it for you.